# Haskell: Resolving dispatch to correct typeclass

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

I'm a little bit confused about how Haskell dispatches to the correct function in a typeclass. Is this done implicitly, or does this have something to do with how Haskell infers the type of something? For instance, consider the following:

```
instance Monad Parser where
     return a = Parser (\ cs -> [(a, cs)])
```

If I do something like:

```
return something >>= \x -> -- Returning a parser!
```

Does haskell guess which return to call using the right side of the bind? How does it know to call the Parser return as opposed to some other one?

Edit:

Okay, so this actually raises more questions for me. I get how Haskell could infer what "return" should be by solving type declarations. However, what about in the case of a totally ambiguous statement?

For instance, what if I open up the interpreter and enter `return 1`? How does it know which return to call then?

Comment: GHCi statements are first assumed to be of the type `IO a` for some *a*, and executed (failing that, it tries `print it`, where *it* is the expression you entered), so since `return 1` fits the type `(Num a) => IO a`, it is executed; the `Num` instance is picked with Haskell's defaulting mechanism (it'll be Integer).

Comment: `let x :: (Monad m, Num n) => m n; x = return 1` Check it out, `x` is a *polymorphic value*! It can be used in *any* situation, as long as the situation requires a value with a type has the shape `m n` and conforms to the constraints: `m` is a `Monad`, `n` is a `Num`. `x` could be `[1.0] :: [Double]`, `Just 1 :: Maybe Int` ... all sorts of things!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct -- Haskell can dispatch on the return type. In fact, since Haskell is a functional language, there is no strict notion of a "return type". For example, is `Int` in `(Bool -> Int) -> String` a return type?

So, how does this happen? First, Haskell infers the type for an expression. It has the form

```
forall x1 x2 [...] . Ctx => t
```

where `Ctx` is the context and has the form `(Class1 vars1, Class2 vars2, ...)`.

Now, in most cases (like in yours) all the type variables that occur in the context also occur in the type `t`. Hence, once those variables are instantiated to concrete types, it's possible to resolve overloaded methods.

Specifically, in your case, Haskell knows that the bind operator `>>=` has the type

```
m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b.
```

Since the right operand has the type `Parser b` for some `b`, the `m` variable must be `Parser`, so `return` has type `a -> Parser a`.

In some cases there might be variables in the context which do not occur in `t`.

E.g.

```
show (read "blah")
```

has the type `String`, but to be evaluated it needs to choose some instance of both `Read` and `Show` classes.

In that case it is either resolved using the *defaulting mechanism*, or an error is reported. In the latter case you can fix it by providing an explicit signature.

Comment: `In fact, since Haskell is a functional language, there is no strict notion of a "return type".` -- What? Consider a function type `t -> u`: The `u` fits "return type" like a T. The return value (or result, if you prefer that terminology) of every function `f :: t -> u` has type `u`. As for your example: The `Int` in `(Bool -> Int) -> String` is indeed a return type, namely the return type of the function that is the higher order function's argument. `String` is the return type of said higher order function.

Comment: @delnan: it is a return type for that inner function, but for the whole thing it's just a part of the type of its argument. Another example: is `a` a return type in `Foo a -> b`? You need to know how `Foo` is implemented to answer that. And if it's an abstract type?

Comment: The return type of `Foo a -> b` is `b`, period. If you know more about the function argument, you can go all recursive and add whether the argument is a function and what *its* return type is. But that's just extra credit, it's irrelevant when considering the result type of the top-level functon. Don't let higher order functions confuse you: Each function has exactly one argument (type) and exactly one result (type). Either may be a function, but to Haskell, functions are just regular values.

Comment: @delnan: anyway, my point was that there's no reason to treat the return type differently in this context. It's just a part of the whole type.

Answer (score 1):

The "return 1" is handled by ghc and ghci by the little see Haskell command "default".

This convenience is formally documented in the [Haskell 98 Report here](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4).  The "default" declaration in the Prelude, which you may override, is:

```
default (Integer,Double)
```

The purpose of "default" is so that something that produces a type which is an instance of "Num" will not require an explicit type annotation in the most common situations.  The meaning of the above "default" declaration is for the compiler to try the Integer type first then try the Double type.  The first type to allow correct compilation is chosen.  This can be turned off entirely by writing:

```
default ()
```

Or you can make a list with your own hints to the compiler, but the standard limits you to only listing types defined in the Prelude or otherwise explicitly allowed by your compiler.  Thus you are not guaranteed the right to list your new data types in the "default" declaration.

With GHC the defaulting rules are in [section 2.4.5 of the user manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules).   GHC always allows you to use your new "Num" types in "default".  Also, by turning on the language extension "ExtendedDefaultRules" the "default" declaration can give defaults to "Show", "Eq", and "Ord" instances.  A simple example for Num:

```
module Main where

data K = K deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)

instance Num K where fromInteger _ = K

default (K)

main = print 0
```

When run in ghci this prints the letter "K"

Answer (score 0):

> For instance, what if I open up the interpreter and enter return 1?

Have you tried this?

> How does it know which return to call then?

Actually, it doesn't.
In such cases, you need to specify the type so it can do the right thing. For example:

```
return 1 :: Maybe Int
```

Comment: I'd be too nice to tell me the reason for downvoting?